# ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] Flex operation

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I already checked all the quotas and they seem to be fine. Don't know what cause the error?

```
Updating service [default] (this may take several minutes)...failed. 

ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] Flex operation projects/objreg-278609/regions/us-central1/operations/214e2dcc-8a7a-4204-898a-580dc14e6a97 error [INTERNAL]: An internal error occurred while processing task /appengine-flex-v1/insert_flex_deployment/flex_create_resources>2020-05-28T10:58:17.771Z15266.ow.8: Deployment Manager operation objreg-278609/operation-1590663498298-5a6b334c5f340-589a82aa-ed20dd6f errors: [code: "RESOURCE_ERROR"
location: "/deployments/aef-default-20200528t054325/resources/aef-default-20200528t054325"
message: "{\"ResourceType\":\"compute.beta.regionAutoscaler\",\"ResourceErrorCode\":\"403\",\"ResourceErrorMessage\":{\"code\":403,\"errors\":[{\"domain\":\"usageLimits\",\"message\":\"Exceeded limit \'QUOTA_FOR_INSTANCES\' on resource \'aef-default-20200528t054325\'. Limit: 8.0\",\"reason\":\"limitExceeded\"}],\"message\":\"Exceeded limit \'QUOTA_FOR_INSTANCES\' on resource \'aef-default-20200528t054325\'. Limit: 8.0\",\"statusMessage\":\"Forbidden\",\"requestPath\":\"https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/beta/projects/objreg-278609/regions/us-central1/autoscalers\",\"httpMethod\":\"POST\"}}"
]
```

Please help me solve it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a know issue. Have a look at [this case](https://issuetracker.google.com/157161938) at the Google Public Issue Tracker.

Google App Engine product team is already aware of this issue and it is currently being investigated. You can follow [this case](https://issuetracker.google.com/157161938) to be informed about progress or possible workarounds.

Unfortunately, there's no ETA at the moment.

As a possible workaround you can set the max num instances to less than 8 (as per the error message).